# explanation of reverse automatic differentiation with language of manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, smooth-manifolds

I heard that forward mode automatic differentiation correspond to tangent vectors,and reverse mode ad correspond to cotangent vectors,is this correct? And what is the detailed construction?

Comment: Does this help? https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11592

Comment: Great paper ! Thanks!